# Integrating PHPSpellCheck into YUI RTE

Tags: php, yui, integration, rte, spell-checking

I have everything set up to integrate PHPSpellCheck (http://www.phpspellcheck.com) to the YUI Rich Text Editor - I have the button made, I have the spell check program in and working - I'm missing one thing - the function phpspellcheck calls.  To integrate the spell check to YUI, I am using this call:

```
this.toolbar.on('splchkClick', function(o) {?????, myEditor, true);
```

but I can't figure out what to put in place of the ???? - a function or an action - I know, but pouring through the phpspellcheck files, I can't figure out where I find out what is happening when I click it's spell check button.  Here's the integration code for phpspellcheck:

```
require ("/var/www/html/evoHTDOCS/phpspellcheck/include.php");
$mySpell = new SpellCheckButton();
$mySpell->InstallationPath = "/phpspellcheck/";
$mySpell->Fields = "EDITORS";
echo $mySpell->SpellImageButton();
```

the source files for the includes of phpspellcheck (there are only two really, include.php and include.js and you can grab them at that website above) seem simple enough, but I don't know how to read jscript and I think that's where it's doing the magic.  Does anyone have any hints on what I might replace ????? with?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.toolbar.on('splchkClick', doPhpSpell , myEditor, true);
```

---

```
function  doPhpSpell(){
PHPLiveSpell_0.CheckInWindow()
}
```

You may want to look at the PHPSpellCheck Javascript API:
http://www.phpspellcheck.com/Javascript-AJAX-Spell-Check-API